# React Native: Prevent animation from blocking app?

Tags: javascript, react-native, animation

I've built a react native animation to show a placeholder/loader when loading a list of articles:

```
    Animated.loop(
      Animated.sequence([
        Animated.timing(this._animation_state.opacity, {
          toValue: this._animation_state.target_opacity,
          duration: this.props.animationDuration,
          delay: this.props.animationDelay,
          useNativeDriver: true
        }),
        Animated.timing(this._animation_state.opacity, {
          toValue: this.props.minOpacity,
          duration: this.props.animationDuration,
          useNativeDriver: true
        })
      ]),
      {
        iterations: 1
      }
    ).start(() => this.startAnimation())
```

This component is used to show the articles are loading in another component like so:

```
render() {
  return (
      {this.state.articles.length === 0 ? (
      <Loader articles={this.state.articles} />
    ) : (
      <TableOfContents navigation={this.props.navigation} />
    )}
  );
}
```

The problem is that the animation blocks the check `this.state.articles.length === 0` until it is complete, thus essentially making itself synchronous/blocking (and thus useless).

Is there any way to make sure this animation does not block the thread from updating and checking the state? `useNativeDriver` doesn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: Where do you put your animation ? in the render ? Animation shouldn't block your render

Comment: Correct, it's inside the render function (updated question)

Comment: are you updating this.state.articles in your Loader ? You only should have <Loader /> without props (if Loader is only a Loading animation without logic), because you want the Loader to be an animated item you can call/remove anytime you want.

Comment: `this.state.articles` is updated outside `Loader`. The reason I passed it in as a prop was a hack to check the article length and start the loop again or return after each iteration (as it was otherwise running infinitely)

Comment: I don't understand why it blocks your render. If you try to setState your articles with an Animated delay or setTimeout, does it affect the render or you still need to wait for the loader to stop ? That would mean your state is not setting correctly, but in any case the parents shouldn't wait the child to finish something until it is clearly defined.

Comment: OH my goodness... after going through an endless rabbit hole thinking it had to do with issues of parent/child prop/state passing/updating, it turns out all it has to do with is this: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/animated#loop `loops can prevent VirtualizedList-based components from rendering more rows while the animation is running. You can pass isInteraction: false in the child animation config to fix this.`

Answer (score 1):

Via https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/animated#loop

> loops can prevent VirtualizedList-based components from rendering more rows while the animation is running. You can pass isInteraction: false in the child animation config to fix this.

Thus, updating the animation like so fixes this headache:

```
Animated.loop(
  Animated.sequence([
    Animated.timing(this._animation_state.opacity, {
      toValue: this._animation_state.target_opacity,
      duration: this.props.animationDuration,
      delay: this.props.animationDelay,
      useNativeDriver: true,
      isInteraction: false
    }),
    Animated.timing(this._animation_state.opacity, {
      toValue: this.props.minOpacity,
      duration: this.props.animationDuration,
      useNativeDriver: true,
      isInteraction: false
    })
  ]),
  {
    iterations: -1
  }
).start()
```